# PyZDDE: Cannot pass filter string to detector viewer for NSC mode

Tags: python, dde

I'm running NSC raytraces in Zemax, using the python zemax DDE server [pyZDDE](https://github.com/indranilsinharoy/PyZDDE/wiki) to run through multiple configurations. Ideally I'd like it to run through all model configurations and perform a small amount of analysis so that I can leave the models processing overnight.

Part of this analysis involves using a filter string to get detector output for a couple of different wavelengths, however when I try to pass my filter string (in this case 'W2', I get the error "ValueError: could not convert string to float: W2"

The full error is:

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyzdde\zdde.py", line 9397, in zGetDetectorViewer
ret = _zfu.readDetectorViewerTextFile(pyz, textFileName, displayData)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyzdde\zfileutils.py", line 679, in readDetectorViewerTextFile
posX = float(line_list[smoothLineNum + 2].split(':')[1].strip()) # 'Detector X'

ValueError: could not convert string to float: W2
```

So to me it looks like its mistaking the filter string for the detector infromation, but I'm not sure how to fix it!

Solutions I've tried:

1. Checking the encoding- I'm using ASCII, but running it in utf-8
   hasn't changed the error.
2. Running a detector .CFG file generated by Zemax that gives the
   desired output when not run though pyZDDE.

Minimal working example:

```
import pyzdde.zdde as pyz
#get rid of any non closed connections possibly hanging around
pyz.closeLink()
#Connect to server
ln = pyz.createLink()
status = ln.zDDEInit()

ln.zSetTimeout(1e5)

filename = 'C:\\...\\Zemax\\Samples\\MultiConfigLens.zmx'
# Load a lens file into the ZEMAX DDE server
ln.zLoadFile(filename)

#Generate config files
configFile0 = 'C:\\...\Zemax\\Samples\\MultiConfigLens_Config1.CFG' 
configFile1 = 'C:\\...\Zemax\\Samples\\MultiConfigLens_Config1.CFG' 
configFile2 = 'C:\\...\Zemax\\Samples\\MultiConfigLens_Config2.CFG'

ln.zSetDetectorViewerSettings(settingsFile=configFile0, surfNum=1, detectNum=10, showAs=0, scale = 1,dType=4)
ln.zSetDetectorViewerSettings(settingsFile=configFile1, surfNum=1, detectNum=10, zrd='RAYS1.ZRD', dfilter='W1',showAs=0, scale=1,  dType=4)
ln.zSetDetectorViewerSettings(settingsFile=configFile2, surfNum=1, detectNum=10, zrd='RAYS1.ZRD', dfilter='W2',showAs=0, scale=1,  dType=4)

#perform the ray trace
ln.zNSCTrace(1,0,split = 1,scatter = 1,usePolar = 1,ignoreErrors = 1,randomSeed = 0,save = 1,saveFilename = 'RAYS1.ZRD',timeout = 1e5)

#grab that detector data
data0 = ln.zGetDetectorViewer(configFile0,displayData = True)
data1 = ln.zGetDetectorViewer(configFile1,displayData = True)
data2 = ln.zGetDetectorViewer(configFile2,displayData = True)
```

as soon as the code gets to "data1" it fails and returns the above error message- any help would be super appreciated!

EDIT: I found the source of the problem, and I'll post the explaination I submitted as a bug report on the [pyZDDE github page](https://github.com/indranilsinharoy/PyZDDE/issues/78):

Looking through readDetectorViewerTextFile in zfileutils (around line 678) it looks like the function doesn't account for the fact that the text file outputted by the detector is changed when a ray database and a filter string are included in the detector config meaning that it attempts to read the filter string as the detector X position, causing the value error.